# MathJax automatic line breaking not working

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I am using MathJax to display Math in my web page. This is how I load and configure it:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { fonts: ["TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
  });
</script>
<script src="//mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

That script is placed as last entry inside `<body>`. Before it, I have some (long) math equation like:

```html
<body>
$$
    a + b + c + d + \int_a^b f(x)dx - \sum_k c_k\int g(x)dx = \prod_n \int_{\Omega_k} F(x,y,z) d\omega
$$ 
...
```

#### Problem

When I load the page, it renders the equation fine. However, when I set the page size to be very narrow and refresh/load the page; the equation is not rendered in a way to fit the page.

The [MathJax doc](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/HTML-CSS.html) states that `linebreaks: { automatic: true }` can be used to automatically break long expressions. Why isn't this working?

**Live demo:** I have published a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/andry-tino/pen/qGZOmZ).

---

#### Troubleshooting

I have also found similar issues like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628064/mathjax-automatic-line-breaking-when-resizing). The CodePen there works, I do not understand why my code does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that your inline configuration is at odds with the combined configuration file loaded alongside MathJax (via the query string).

Inline, you're setting up the HTML-CSS output alongside automatic linebreaking for it.
However, the combined configuration file loads the CommonHTML output.

The last update to the configuration comes from the combined configuration file, so you end up with the CommonHTML output (you can check this via the MathJax context menu and also switch to HTML-CSS there -- NB: this sets a cookie).

So you can either update your inline configuration or switch the combined configuration.

I'd suggest using the CommonHTML output which is newer and faster than the now positively ancient HTML-CSS output (which was designed when IE8 was new). You can also add `-full` to the query string to get a larger payload if you know you'll have content to render (otherwise MathJax first looks for content before loading more components).

```css
body { width: 10em}
```

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    "CommonHTML": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
  });
</script>
<script src="//mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

$$
    a + b + c + d + \int_a^b f(x)dx - \sum_k c_k\int g(x)dx = \prod_n \int_{\Omega_k} F(x,y,z) d\omega
$$
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear it helped.

Comment: Note that nowadays latest MathJax version is 3.x series which does not yet implement automatic linebreaking at all. If you nede linebreaking, you have to use version 2.x.