# Automatic linebreaks not working with mathjax in my site, but the same equation tested in any online mathjax live demo works fine

Tags: html, css, jekyll, mathjax

In a Jekyll / Github Pages site I built, a mathjax equation is rendered without linebreaks. However, the exact same equation code, pasted in an online mathjax generator, renders just fine, even with the SAME mathjax configuration and loading scripts.

I have tried many different configuration and loading scripts, including several from solutions to similar issues [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56071794/mathjax-automatic-line-breaking-not-working), to no avail.

I have been modifying my css a lot to finish the styling of my site, and am beginning to think this might have something to do (because other than the css, [the HTML and the JS scripts for mathjax are the same in the online rendering sites](https://jsbin.com/sacexoxosa/2/edit?html,output)).

My current mathjax config and load scripts:

```html
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        tex2jax: {
          inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
          displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
          processEscapes: true
        },
        "CommonHTML": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
      });
    </script>
    <script src="//mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

The equation:

```latex
\begin{aligned}
  & \phi(x,y) = \phi \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i, \sum_{j=1}^n y_je_j \right)
  = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_i y_j \phi(e_i, e_j) = \\
  & (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
      \phi(e_1, e_1) & \cdots & \phi(e_1, e_n) \\
      \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      \phi(e_n, e_1) & \cdots & \phi(e_n, e_n)
    \end{array} \right)
  \left( \begin{array}{c}
      y_1 \\
      \vdots \\
      y_n
    \end{array} \right)
\end{aligned}
```

Here is how it renders in my site:
[Overflows the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB8T7.png)

Here is how it renders in the [online tool](https://jsbin.com/sacexoxosa/2/edit?html,output):
[auto line wrapping done correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iENul.png)

My [CSS](https://github.com/amaynez/amaynez.github.io/blob/master/assets/css/main.css) and [Markdown](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amaynez/amaynez.github.io/master/_posts/2021-01-20-Markdown-the-language-of-blogs.md) to generate the page through jekyll/kramdown.

Comment: I suspect that your site is converting the `\\ ` to a single backslash (this might happen if you are using Markdown as your entry format, for example).  Try doubling all the backslashes, so that `\\ ` becomes `\\\\ `.

Comment: I’ll tes this tonight.